# 220V GFCI circuit breaker neutral

Tags: electrical, gfci, 240v

I have a 220V 15 amp body dryer with 2 prongs on the plug (European). Manufacturer instructions indicate to connect 2 hots and 1 ground to the receptacle. Since this is in a bathroom, I have installed a GFCI 2 pole breaker, which requires a neutral from the receptacle.  Without a neutral from the GFCI, the breaker trips. I just finished wiring my other GFCI single pole circuits to include the neutral from the receptacle, walla no more trips. How do I wire this? If I need to run a neutral, what size? I am using a 20 amp circuit.

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: I am located in California

Comment: What make and model is your panel, and the GFCI breaker in question? Also, it sounds weird that a GFCI would require a *load*-side neutral for a 220V only appliance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GFCIs work by making sure current is equal in and out (i.e. that all current is accounted for).  As such, all (normal) current must pass through a GFCI device: All hots and any neutral.

Normally one attaches the neutral wire to the neutral bar.  The GFCI instructions are warning that *you can't do the normal thing*, and "the" neutral wire must go through the GFCI breaker (for detection purposes) just like all the hot(s).

Since  your circuit does not employ a neutral wire, this advice is irrelevant to you.

---

When wiring this circuit, you may find it prudent to run a /3 cable so it can be used later for some other appliance which may want neutral.  In that case, leave the full length on the neutral wires, but cap them off.

---

All that said, the GFCI breaker will have a "neutral pigtail" (literally looks like a pig's tail, it's all curled up) -- this is where the GFCI gets the *supply-side* neutral from.  You will probably need to plug that into the neutral bar on the panel; many 240V GFCIs need it to power their own onboard electronics.

As with all GFCIs, hook up the GFCI itself and get it fully working *before* attaching **anything** to the load side.  You will easily catch any such problem in this area.